# Is there any way to not send Authorization token directly in every request

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, authentication, jwt, token

I am practicing a project which has ruby on rails as a backend, React JS as a frontend.
I do understand that After authentication/login, I have to send authorization token along with every request to server which is quite duplicating. Is there any automated way to do this process and not send Authorization token in header for every request.

Environment

1. ReactJS (front-end)
2. Ruby On Rails (back-end)
3. Fetch for response

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new instance of axios with a custom config,
example as below;

```
import axios from 'axios';
const loadToken = () => sessionStorage.get('token');
const BASE_URL = 'url';

const getHeader = () => {
  const token = loadToken();
  return {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
};

const axiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    config.baseURL = BASE_URL;
    config.headers = getHeader();
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9xxfjj?file=src%2Frepo.js,src%2Faxios-instance.js)

Comment: Elvin can you please share the whole snippet where you actually calling the api?

Comment: Stackblitz link is added